# Event handler preventing submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the very simple code below that installs an event handler on confirmPass keystrokes.  On registration form submit I want to be able to disable the submit if the passwords do not match.  In the 'onClick' event for the registration form if I call confirmPass() it fails to submit, if I comment it out it submits.  Why is confirmPass() blocking the programatic form submit?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $('#confirmPassword').keyup(function(){
        confirmPass();
    })
});
function registrationSubmit(){
    confirmPass();
    $('#registration').submit();
}
function confirmPass() {
    var pass = $('#password').val();
    var cpass = $('#confirmPassword').val();
    if (!(pass == cpass)) {
        $('#confirmPassword').addClass('text-danger');
        $('#cpassmsg').addClass('text-danger').removeClass('ui-helper-hidden');
        $('#cpassmsg').text("Confirm Password Fails")
        $('#registration').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        return;
    } else {
        $('#confirmPassword').addClass('text-success').removeClass('text-danger');
        $('#cpassmsg').addClass('text-success').removeClass('text-danger');
        $('#cpassmsg').text("Confirm Password Match!")
    }
```

Comment: Every time confirmation fails, you add an event listener that calls `preventDefault()`. You never remove these when confirmation succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line adds an event handler.

```
$('#registration').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Which means every time the submit event is fired after this line have been hit it will be cancelled. Since you call `confirmPass` on each keystroke the line will be executed at least once and thus submits events on the form will **always** be cancelled. Instead you might want to only call submit only if the validations are succesfull and remove the line I mentionned above

Exemple

```
function registrationSubmit(event){
    // Assuming you modify confirmPass to return true/false
    if(confirmPass()){
       $('#registration').submit();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You never remove the submit handlers that call `preventDefault()`.

Instead of adding a handler in `confirmPass()`, check whether the password is valid in `registrationSubmit()`. Have `confirmPass()` return a boolean to indicate this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");
  $('#confirmPassword').keyup(function() {
    confirmPass();
  })
});

function registrationSubmit() {
  if (confirmPass())
    $('#registration').submit();
  }
}

function confirmPass() {
  var pass = $('#password').val();
  var cpass = $('#confirmPassword').val();
  if (pass != cpass) {
    $('#confirmPassword').addClass('text-danger');
    $('#cpassmsg').addClass('text-danger').removeClass('ui-helper-hidden');
    $('#cpassmsg').text("Confirm Password Fails")
    return false;
  } else {
    $('#confirmPassword').addClass('text-success').removeClass('text-danger');
    $('#cpassmsg').addClass('text-success').removeClass('text-danger');
    $('#cpassmsg').text("Confirm Password Match!");
    return true;
  }
}
```